# Spring Boot threads and data loading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I am building an app using Spring Boot. I have some utility classes that read in files and create hashmaps from them.

When a user connects to Spring, I believe they hit the controller first. Is a controller thread built and spawned for every user? Would this cause a class that reads in a file upon the app creation to have to read in the file every time a user connects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread-safe Controller and Utility Classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112445/thread-safe-controller-and-utility-classes)